# Finding the MLEs for pi in a contingency table proof

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multinomial-distribution, poisson-regression, contingency-tables, lagrange-multipliers

Reference: https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c5.pdf

In a two-dimensional table, (the multinomial model - section 5.1.2 in the link above), I was wondering how they get $$\hat\pi_{i.} = \frac{y_{i.}}{n}$$ and $$\hat\pi_{.j} = \frac{y_{.j}}{n}$$

Under the null hypothesis, $$H_0: \pi_{ij} = \pi_{i.}\pi_{.j} $$

I have gone through several papers and I see that the result above is consistent among all, however, I am unsure how to set up the LaGrange multiplier and how to solve it.
TIA!

Answer (score 1):

So, we can write the log-likelihood as $\sum_i\sum_jy_{ij}\log(\pi_{i.}\cdot\pi_{.j})$, which means that the Lagrangian is:

$$\mathcal L=\sum_i\sum_jy_{ij}\log(\pi_{i.}\cdot\pi_{.j})-\lambda\sum_i\pi_{i.}-\mu\sum_j\pi_{.j}$$

Now, we can separate the log of the product as the sum of the logs and do some manipulations:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal L&=\sum_i\sum_jy_{ij}\log(\pi_{i.}\cdot\pi_{.j})-\lambda\sum_i\pi_{i.}-\mu\sum_j\pi_{.j}\\
&=\sum_i\sum_jy_{ij}\log\pi_{i.}+\sum_i\sum_jy_{ij}\log\pi_{.j}-\lambda\sum_i\pi_{i.}-\mu\sum_j\pi_{.j}\\
&=\sum_iy_{i.}\log\pi_{i.}+\sum_jy_{.j}\log\pi_{.j}-\lambda\sum_i\pi_{i.}-\mu\sum_j\pi_{.j}\\
&=\left(\sum_iy_{i.}\log\pi_{i.}-\lambda\sum_i\pi_{i.}\right)+\left(\sum_jy_{.j}\log\pi_{.j}-\mu\sum_j\pi_{.j}\right)\\
\end{align}$$

Now, we have one term that depends only on $\pi_{i.}$ (the first parenthesis) and one term that depends only on $\pi_{.j}$ (the second parenthesis). You can maximize them individually, and the mathematical steps are very similar to finding MLE for a simple multinomial. After taking derivatives and equating to zero, you will get the MLE mentioned in your reference.

Hope it was helpful!

Comment: Say I want to look at $$\pi_{i.}$$, when I take the partial, I get: $$\frac{y_{i.}}{\pi_{i.}} - \lambda = 0$$. My concern with this is how do I treat $$\lambda$$ here? Thanks for the quick reply :D

Comment: OK, so now you have $\pi_{i.}=\lambda y_{i.}$, and you have to find $\lambda$. Then you should use the fact that $\sum_i\pi_{i.}=1$, and since $\sum_i\pi_{i.}=\lambda\sum_i\y_{i.}=n\lambda$, you get $1=n\lambda$ or $\lambda=1/n$. Finally, you get $\pi_{i.}=\lambda y_{i.}=y_{i.}/n$. Hope this wasn't too confusing!